# As I can use different models in the same controller action

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I'm trying to send to the view, information from multiple models as follows:

```
var tareasGlob = "";
var directoresProy = "";
var usuariosGlob = "";
var proyectosGlob = "";

module.exports = {


'index' : function(req, res, next){

    // De esta forma se utlisaria la funcion de utilidad que cree en el archivo /api/services/utility.js
    // utility.sliceIt();


    Tarea.find().done(function(err, tareas){
        if(err){ return res.serverError(err); } 
        tareasGlob = tareas; 
    });
    console.log('tareas', tareasGlob);
    DirectorProy.find().done(function(err, directsproy){
        if(err){ return res.serverError(err); } 
        directoresProy = directsproy;
    });

    Usuario.find().done(function(err, usuarios){
        if(err){ return res.serverError(err); } 
        usuariosGlob = usuarios;
    });

    Proyecto.find().done(function(err, proyectos){
        if(err){ return res.serverError(err); } 
        proyectosGlob = proyectos;
    });



    res.view({
        'tareas'         : tareasGlob,
        'directoresproy' : directoresProy,
        'usuarios'       : usuariosGlob,
        'proyectos'      : proyectosGlob
    });

},
```

but then an error occurs because when I do the "res.view ()" are not yet assigned values ​​to variables and are shipped empty.

Thanks in advance for the help you can give me to correct the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are node packages available to help you with asynchronous coding problems like this one.  Sails globalizes the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library, which would allow you to rewrite your code as:

```
// All four of the functions inside `async.auto` will run in parallel,
// and if successful their results will be passed to the "allDone"
// function
async.auto({
    tareas: function(cb) {
        Tarea.find().exec(cb);
    },
    directsproy: function(cb) {
        DirectorProy.find().exec(cb);
    },
    usuarios: function(cb) {
        Usuario.find().exec(cb);
    },
    proyectos: function(cb) {
        Proyecto.find().exec(cb);
    }
}, function allDone(err, results) {
    // If any of the functions called the callback with an error,
    // allDone will immediately be called with the error as the
    // first argument
    if (err) {return res.serverError(err);}

    // Otherwise, `results` will be an object whose keys are the
    // same as those of the first argument (tareas, directsproy,
    // usuarios and proyectos, and whose values are the results
    // of their `find` queries.
    res.view(results);
});
```

You can also use `async.auto` to declare dependencies between the different functions, use `async.forEach` to do asynchronous looping over arrays, and all sorts of fun stuff.

Full docs for async [here](https://github.com/caolan/async).

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that all 4 of those find methods have completed before calling res.view. I'd say have a counter that keeps track of how many responses you've received, incrementing by 1 each time a response comes back. And then move res.view into a method that checks that the var == 4 and, if it doesn't returns.

Something like (could be errors below):

```
'index' : function(req, res, next){
  var counter = 0;

// De esta forma se utlisaria la funcion de utilidad que cree en el archivo /api/services/utility.js
// utility.sliceIt();


Tarea.find().done(function(err, tareas){
    if(err){ return res.serverError(err); } 
    tareasGlob = tareas; 
    counter++;
    this.returnView(res);
});
console.log('tareas', tareasGlob);
DirectorProy.find().done(function(err, directsproy){
    if(err){ return res.serverError(err); } 
    directoresProy = directsproy;
    counter++;
    this.returnView(res);
});

Usuario.find().done(function(err, usuarios){
    if(err){ return res.serverError(err); } 
    usuariosGlob = usuarios;
    counter++;
    this.returnView(res);
});

Proyecto.find().done(function(err, proyectos){
    if(err){ return res.serverError(err); } 
    proyectosGlob = proyectos;
    counter++;
    this.returnView(res);
});



res.view({
    'tareas'         : tareasGlob,
    'directoresproy' : directoresProy,
    'usuarios'       : usuariosGlob,
    'proyectos'      : proyectosGlob
});

},

returnView: function(res){
    if (counter < 4)
      return;
// return view logic here

}
```